# comparing any two permutations of elements of an array or some set-all elements distinct

Tags: arrays, permutation

I am trying to find the greater permutation of elements `(all distinct)` of an array. Let's assume - we have an array `{1,2,3}` then its permutations are `{1,2,3}, {1,3,2}, {2,1,3}, {2,3,1},{3,1,2},{3,2,1}`.

I want to know which `permutation` is greater than the other and how?

if possible use an array of size 4 or more to explain.

> For Example:
> **EX1.** m = {1,2,3} and n={2,3,1} then, I think, 
>   n>m because
>
> ```
> case 1:<br> I consider the first difference where the n(0)>m(0) and hence permutations n>m . 
> <br><br>
>  case 2:  <br> n(0) > m(0)  and n(1) > m(1)  though n(2) < m(2).Hence, n>m. 
> <br> which case shall I consider?
> ```
>
> **EX2:**
>  p=[2,3,1] and q=[1,3,2] ,
>
> ```
>  p > q because p(0) > q(0)  &  p(1) = q(1) even though p(2) < q(2). 
>
> Am I correct? <br>
>  Take examples to explain all this  and think as if you are explaining a child.
> ```

Comment: What you want is called [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). You explain perfectly what you want; what is your exact question? Implementation? Language-related?

Comment: @Thomas Baruchel here the problem link. I just want to understand how one permutation  can be greater than  the other. - https://www.codechef.com/NOV16/problems/CPERM -  please do not explain the solution I will do that on my own.

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel I have gotten  what I need to do. I was getting it wrong. Thanks.